# SQL Server max_length for nvarchar

Tags: sql-server

In [docs for SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939(v=sql.110).aspx) is said:

... *The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered **+ 2 bytes***.

What means these 2 additional bytes? 
Because for field nvarchar( 160 ) *sys.columns.max_length*  returns 320. There is no extra 2 bytes.

Comment: it is talking about how much disk storage space, which evidently is 2 bytes more than the length of the string. max length deals with length only, not storage size.

Comment: max_length?   are you sure you're using sql-server?   I'm not finding max_length as a valid sql server function.

Comment: @TabAlleman I wonder if OP is using either information_schema or another dmv to view max length of field.

Comment: 2 bytes overhead for the column offset array.